# Does anyone know what this is actually called?

Tags: lua, bytecode

I have been wondering what this is actually called for a long time because a while ago (like 3 years ago) I thought it was called bytecode but since then I have realized what bytecode actually is. I'll give an example because I don't really know what to call it.

It looks like this:
`\234\22\21\65\22\76\54\87`. It's basically the byte of all the characters preceded by a backslash.

Does anyone know what this is called?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, it sort of looks like the escaped string `êAL6W` :(

Comment: Do you know a name that I could use to reference it on google or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Lua reference manual:

> We can specify any byte in a short literal string by its numeric value
>   (including embedded zeros). This can be done with the escape sequence
>   \xXX, where XX is a sequence of exactly two hexadecimal digits, or
>   with the **escape sequence \ddd, where ddd is a sequence of up to three
>   decimal digits**. (Note that if a decimal escape sequence is to be
>   followed by a digit, it must be expressed using exactly three digits.)

Also refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal#Escape_sequences

Comment: Yeah, but `êAL6W` is a weird string. I think there's more to this.

Comment: It's a bit complicated in Lua because strings are counted sequences of bytes and _can_ be passed to or returned from text functions and _can_ be expressed in literal strings as characters. In those cases, the selected locale gives a byte value a character meaning and vice versa. So, by being a counted sequence, it's a big step up from C.